# Stored Procedure Does Not Appear in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I added stored procedure to my sql database.It works in database.

If ı use entity framework(Linq), i can see all stored procedure however below stored procedure does not appear.I can not see it.

Where i miss ?

```
**USE [CRM_DEMO]  
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_MUSTERI_AD_KONTROL_ET] 2.10.2013 09:58:27   ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MUSTERI_AD_KONTROL_ET]
(
@MUSTERI_DURUM BIT,
@MUSTERI_ADI VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT MUSTERI_ADI FROM MUSTERILER 
WHERE MUSTERI_DURUMU=@MUSTERI_DURUM AND MUSTERI_ADI=@MUSTERI_ADI 
END  
**
```

Comment: Have you Updated your data model from the Database?

Answer (score 0):

I found it's solution.

Problem occurs because of not getting Primary Key ,

I added

Select * from....

I solved it..